# problem: Limit of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For each $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, there exists $J_{n}$ finite set in $\mathbb{N}$ and $a_{i,n} \geq 0$ for $i \in J_{n}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\sum\limits_{i \in J_{n}} a_{i,n} = 0 $.

Suppose that there exists the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\sum\limits_{i \in J_{n}} i.a_{i,n}$. Can we say that  $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\sum\limits_{i \in J_{n}} i.a_{i,n} = 0$?

I think that it is not true. I found some questions related with it:

[real analysis: $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum n a_{n^2}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716746/real-analysis-sum-a-n-converges-if-and-only-if-sum-n-a-n2-converges)

[Relate $\sum{a_n}$ and $\sum{n a_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888928/relate-suma-n-and-sumn-a-n)

[If $\sum n a_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum |a_n|^p$ converges for $p>1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035358/if-sum-n-a-n-converges-then-sum-a-n-converges-and-sum-a-np-converge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$J_n=\{n\}$, $a_{n,n}=\dfrac{1}{n}$.

$$\sum_\limits{i\in J_n}a_{i,n}=\frac1n\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

But $$\sum_\limits{i\in J_n}ia_{i,n}=\frac n n\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1$$